# Союз или союзное слово "потому, что"

Tags: синтаксис

> Россия начиналась не с меча,
>   Она с косы и плуга начиналась.
>   Не **потому, что** кровь не горяча,
>   А **потому, что** русского плеча
>   Ни разу в жизни злоба не касалась...

Чем являются выделенные слова в строфе из стихотворения Эдуарда Асадова?

Мне кажется, что союзными словами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Это составные союзы ПОТОМУ ЧТО со значением причины**, расчлененные, при этом местоименные части союзов образуют конструкцию с противопоставлением. Предложение сложноподчиненное, с двумя однородными придаточными причины.

А союзные слова должны являться **членами предложения.**

Comment: Как пишут в методичках, если можно выделить логическим ударением, это союзное слово. Тут все выделяется. В чем подвох?

Comment: Разве это определение для союзного слова? И подвоха нет, на простой союз не падает ударение, а на местоименную часть составного союза  при его расчленении  падает. Эта  местоименная часть по происхождению является указательным словом и входит в состав главного предложения. А союзные слова относятся к придаточной части.

Comment: Нет, но, думается, за уши этот "член предложения" притянуть всегда можно. "Поэтому" же является членом предложения, а что тогда "потому" и "что" мешает?..

Comment: Поэтому - это наречие, средством связи не является, а союзы и союзные слова - это именно средства связи. Просто подчинительный союз членом предложения не является (как и сочинительный  союз), а у союзного слова две функции: и средство связи,  и член предложения (подлежащее, сказуемое, обстоятельство и т.д.)

Comment: а вот *поэтому* в некоторых справочниках считается наречным **союзным словом**. Так что средством связи тоже может являться.

Comment: Справочники разные бывают, вообще-то считается, что единственным союзом для придаточного следствия является союз ТАК ЧТО, а ПОЭТОМУ- это структурный элемент, дополнительно указывающий на  причинно- следственные отношения  в БСП. Ещё я вспомнила на тему ударения такой пример: Он сказал, что он знает об этом (союз, нет ударения). - Он сказал, чтО (именно) он знает об этом (союзное слово  в роли дополнения, ударение).

Comment: довольно большая книжка, много о чем написано, хотя и имеет место "доверяй, но проверяй": Н. Адамчик "Самый полный курс русского языка".

Comment: В грамматике есть спорные моменты, которые разные лингвисты объясняют различным образом, наверное, это нормально.

Comment: Смотрите, в учебнике одном нашел: потому в нашем случае — некое указательное слово, а что — союз.

Comment: Все составные союзы так образуются, в них входит местоименная часть (бывшее указательное слово) и простой союз. Например: для того чтобы, с тем чтобы, затем чтобы (написание предлога может быть слитным или раздельным).  Но это только составные части союза как одной единицы. Также такой пример: ТАК ЧТО может быть следственным союзом, а может быть указ. словом + союзом в придаточных (степень + следствие): Сегодня холодно, так что гулять не пойдем. Сегодня так холодно, что гулять не пойдем.